# Automated Report from Salesforce to Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automation

I am needing to automate a report in Salesforce to go to Journey Builder as a data extension but can't find a good way to do so. I need Journey Builder to receive the updated report daily and then send out emails based on the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an import inside of email studio that will import a sales cloud report:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000273869&language=en_US

From there, you can setup an automation to run daily in automation studio that would look like this:

Import File>SQL Query>Journey Entry

Import File would import the sales cloud report you created, SQL Query would allow you to join to any other tables (Like Subscribers), Journey Entry to inject the results into your journey.

Best,

Kevin

Comment: Important notice: The actual user who is running the report on execution is the Salesforce System User that was defined for the connector - so make sure reports are visible to that user. Also results for "my contacts" for example are based on the SF System User's results and not the one who runs the query!